# Command line php mysqli fails but works via web server and works in local

Tags: php, shell, mysqli, centos

I have a shell script that calls a php script to insert records in database after parsing text file.  When it calls the PHP script I get errors that it cannot find mysqli:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'mysqli' not found in /path/to/php/file.php on line 5
```

This failed in local on Macbook Pro with Nginx and PHP-FPM and Mysql 5.5.x and after I added the socket param to mysqli call, it worked in local.  **This worked with local db!**

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "mydb", 3306, "/tmp/mysql.sock");
```

I deployed to Linux server (CentOS6 that has 'yum install php' with PHP 5.3.x) installed.  I changed the connection to a remote db server so dropped the "/tmp/mysql.sock" because db not running on this server.

Shell script calling php to execute script:

```
php -c "/etc/php.ini" -f "/path/to/php/file.php"
```

Given I am not running mysql locally, how do I get it to recognize the mysqli lib and execute.  It's on CentOS6.  I even tried adding mysqli.so to php.ini file and got following error:

```
[mike@app2 myapp]# php -version
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Feb  2 2012 23:47:49) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
```

Thanks for any help resolving this.  Normally I'd use mysql(query) but need mysqli() for some prepared statements and other bits in the script.

Comment: Don't normally use `mysql_*`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found that mysqli was not installed with PHP and ran the following command:

```
>php -i
```

This returned the phpinfo() and found no mention of mysqli.  I then ran the 'yum' command to install php-mysqli:

```
>yum install php-mysqli
```

After this the script worked successfully.  Hope this helps others that might run into similar.

Answer (score 1):

PHP CLI will have its own environmental setup from that used by the webserver.  If you don't have mysqli available in the CLI environment that would cause this issue.

Comment: Thanks Mike.  Any idea how to add to the CLI environment?

Comment: @MikeS. Did you find out how to add to the CLI environment?  I'm going through this same challenge now.

Comment: @arya look at accepted answer.  Depending on your OS you may need to use different package installer like aptitude

Comment: @MikeBrant: I installed mysqli on Ubuntu LTS 14.04 OS using: `sudo apt-get install php5-mysql`.  The same challenge remains.