# Nette Tester: MySQLi not working

Tags: php, mysqli, nette, nette-tester

Normally, in apache via mod php it works perfectly fine, but if I try function_exists('mysqli_init'), function does not exist.

Other errors shown:

Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()
Class 'MySQLi' not found in <file>

Why MySQLi isn't working and how to fix it? Thanks!

Command used to run test:

```
vendor/bin/tester -c /etc/php5/apache2 -p php
```

Comment: Be careful, PHP CLI and PHP web have two different configurations so what appears while testing from command line may be different for web. Far better to make a webpage with the following in it: <?php phpinfo(); ?> It's plausible mysqli is not configured for CLI on your server, but is for web. Goodluck!

Comment: This may also help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11585399/command-line-php-mysqli-fails-but-works-via-web-server-and-works-in-local

Answer (score 1):

Try running `./vendor/bin/tester -c /etc/php5/apache2 -p php --info` to see which php.ini file and PHP extensions are loaded.

Most-likely the you are going to find out that the MySQLi extension is not loaded because the `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` does not contain the necessary option.

The correct solution is to create specific `php.ini` for your project with necessary extensions.

See also [official documentation](http://tester.nette.org/#toc-own-php-ini):

> The Tester runs PHP processes with -n option, so no php.ini is loaded (**not even that from /etc/php/conf.d/*.ini in UNIX**)

Answer (score 0):

With tester `-c` parameter, you need to provide path to `php.ini` file, not folder containing it.

Also tester resets php environment for repeatable result. It is better idea provide own `php.ini` which only defines needed extesions:

```
[PHP}
extension=mysqli.so
```